# Django admin site that can access multiple tables in one page (site?)

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to utilize Django admin page to build a page that presents information queried from multiple tables, so it looks something like

```
page1:
    account1
    account2
    account3
```

when clicking on `account1`:

```
account1 info page:
    attri1 from table1
    attri2 from table1
    attri1 from table2
    attri1 from table3
```

Essentially I just want to get info from multiple tables, but I'm not sure if Django admin does that. I've always only created sites using one table only. All these tables are linked by a foreignKey (account name)

Is it even possible?

Comment: checkout admin.TabularInline

Comment: @HemanthSP this is perfect. Can you reply to the post so I can mark it as answer?

Comment: @Jcho can check this photo is this do you need https://imageresize.org/view/9295bcd3-9903-4886-b7ed-ee9435dc8729

Comment: @HemanthSP yes that's pretty much what I'm looking for. I'm now looking to formatting and sorting and maybe default some textfield to current user, which is another task.